# Angular momentum of a rigid body about any points

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

Is angular momentum about all points same if the body is rigid and is rotating/translating/rolling with a constant velocity? Why? No external force is acting on the body.

Comment: Are you asking whether if we choose different reference points for calculating the angular momentum we always get the same value? If so, the answer is obviously *no*. In that case are you asking why the answer is obviously *no*?

Comment: Yes, why's it obviously no? Cause, all the points are inertial reference frames.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a surprisingly deep question, because to answer it you need to understand the basic reason conservation laws exist. There is a theorem by the mathematician Emmy Noether, and known not unreasonably as [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem), that tells us conservation laws are related to symmetry.

Conservation of linear momentum is related to [translation symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translational_symmetry). This says that if we move a system some distance in space and the laws of physics are unchanged then linear momentum will be conserved. So if we choose a point for our origin, then measure the momentum of some system, moving our origin will not change the linear momentum.

Conservation of angular momentum is related to [rotational symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_symmetry). This says that if we rotate our system by some arbitrary angle and the laws of physics are unchanged then angular momentum will be conserved. So if we choose an origin and some axes, then measure the momentum of some system, rotating our axes will not change the angular momentum.

However angular momentum is not constant under a translation. If we move our origin and recalculate the angular momentum there is no reason to expect that the angular momentum will be conserved, and indeed it isn't.

I should clarify what I mean by *the laws of physics are unchanged*. Any system can be described by an equation called the [Lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics), and from the Lagrangian we can calculate the equations of motion of the system. When I say the laws of physics aren't changed by a translation I mean the Lagrangian is not changed by the translation, or likewise for rotation that the Lagrangian is unchanged by the rotation.

Comment: Is linear momentum not constant under rotation likewise?

Comment: @Eugene: momentum is a vector so it is only constant if neither its direction nor its magnitude changes. Rotation obviously changes its direction.

Comment: A delightful answer as always! :) This made me realize that the mathematical reason as to why the magnitude of the momentum doesn't change under a rotation would be that the momentum vector transforms under the fundamental representation of $SO(3)$ and its covector under the anti-fundamental of $SO(3)$ which ensures that the norm transforms under the trivial representation by virtue of the fact that $U^TU=I$ for $U\in SO(3)$. @Eugene You might find this "unnecessarily" lengthy explanation nonetheless interesting. Also, correct me if I am mistaken.